# Как сделать правильно acl для www и пользователя?

Tags: linux, acl

Как сделать чтоб acl применялся к подкаталогам и файлам рекурсивно?

Пока сделал так

```
setfacl -Rm u:user:rwX,u:www-data:rwX /var/www/html/
```

но новые файлы могут появляться не с теми правами.

```
# owner: siter
# group: siter
user::rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:www-data:rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Хотя группа прилипла...

Как сделать аналогичное галочке "заменить все записи разрешений дочернего объекта наследуемыми от этого объекта" windows?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для значений ACL по умолчанию для новых файлов нужно установить также *default ACL*:

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:user:rwX,d:u:www-data:rwX
```

Подробности см. в [`man acl`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)

Comment: `setfacl -Rdm u:...` сделал  так.  ничего не сломается если сделаю `-Rx` на подкаталогах?

Comment: @eri, наверно... не должно... зависит от того, что именно ты этим хочешь сделать и какие элементы списка удаляешь...